# umask and file permission issue with php application upload

Tags: linux, symfony, prestashop, plesk, umask

I installed a domain with Prestashop 1.7 on a Plesk Onyx Centos 7 box with pretty standard settings
(PHP-FPM server by Apache - Php7 Plesk handler).
Domain is using its own user / webspace with the classic "psacln" group and files/folder with 644/755 permission.

It happens that when I try to add some new modules from the application backoffice or when the application writes cache files
they are written with 666 permission for files and 777 for folders. 
This looks like totally insecure to me , and it never happened with other domains on the same host with different applications with the same domain setting, where I have the expected result (644 for files / 755 for folders).

I see lot of people are reporting this behaviour, and the answer was
"this is due to Symfony PHP framework used in Prestashop 1.7 that uses server umask setting to set files/folder permission , so check / fix your envoriment because you have wrong umask".

I checked my server and #umask command (launched as root) is reporting 0022 that is supposed to be the correct setting to have 644 / 755 permission during uploads.

So my question is : am I missing something about umask or how Plesk is setting this value ? 
Is there some umask setting I need to check at web-server user level or in Plesk domain configuration ?
Or is the application that needs to be fixed ?

Thank you !

Comment: You can temporarily give SSH access to domain system user, and run `umask` from him to verify.
Plesk does not manage umask in any way.

Comment: I already did that test,
I gave /bin/sh shell access to the same user configured for the involved domain and ran "umask" command - The result is always "0022" , but the files uploaded by Prestashop are still with 666/777 permisssion.